# Sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+2)^{n+2}}{3^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Calculate the sum of the next series and for which values of $x$ it converges:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+2)^{n+2}}{3^n}$$

I used D'Alembert and found that the limit is less than 1, so: $-5 < x < 1$ (because the fraction must be less than 1).

and then I assigned the values: $x=-5$ and $x=1$ in the series and got:

for $x=-5$ and $x=1$, it diverges.

then the series converges in the range of $(-5,1)$, $R=3$ and the center point is for $x=2$.

Please let know if there is a mistake and find the sum.

Comment: It is "D'Alembert".

Comment: In fact it is "d'Alembert".

Comment: @Eckhard The capital D is off? (the e is my usual mistake there)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I was referring to the 'e'. Also I think, one would usually use a lower-case 'd' except at the beginning of of sentence.

Comment: A simpler way would be interpreting it as a geometric progression whose convergence criteria is well known ($|r|<1$ where $r$ is the common ratio of the series.)

Answer (score 3):

for $|(x+2)/3|<1$ it converges to the limit given by multiplication of geometric series limit and polynomial: 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+2)^{n+2}}{3^n}=(x+2)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x+2}{3}\right)^n=(x+2)^2\frac{1}{1-\frac{x+2}{3}} =\frac{3(x+2)^2}{1-x}
$$

for $|(x+2)/3|\geq 1$, the sum is not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Your sum is equal to
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+2)^{n+2}}{3^n}=(x+2)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x+2}{3}\right)^n,
$$
which you recognize as a geometric series $\sum_n q^n$ with sum $1/(1-q)$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+2)^{n+2}}{3^n}=(x+2)^2\frac{1}{1-\frac{x+2}{3}} =\frac{3(x+2)^2}{1-x}
$$ 
as long as $|(x+2)/3|<1$.

If $|(x+2)/3|\geq 1$, the sum is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$for $|x|<1$